# italicization with \textit does not work

Tags: fonts, bold, italic, sans-serif

When I compile the following, ABC is not italicized.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}
\textsf{\textbf{\textit{ABC}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [How to write bold, italic and sans-serif at the same time?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302597/64454)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll notice the following warning in your `.log` file:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/bx/it' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmss/bx/n' instead on input line 4.
```

It suggests that under the OT1 font encoding, there is no **bold** `bx` *italic** `it` version within the `s`ans `s`erif font. So, it substitutes it just for a `n`ormal **bold**, hence the output

[image]

You need a font that includes this typeface. [`lmodern`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm) does:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\textsf{\textbf{\textit{ABC}}}
\end{document}
```